# Populate Jtable with vector

Tags: java, json, vector, jtable

I am trying to populate a JTABLE with JsonArray which has been converted to jsonObject and then to a a vector.

```
Vector<Vector<String>> dataList = new Vector<>();
    for (int x = 0; x <refresh.length(); x++){
        JSONObject jsonTable = refresh.getJSONObject(x);
        Vector <String> data = new Vector <> ();
        jsonTable.getInt("purchaseid");

        data.add((jsonTable.getString("purchaseid")));
        data.add(jsonTable.getString("departmentcode"));
        data.add(jsonTable.getString("deliveryattention"));
        data.add(jsonTable.getString("completedstatus"));
        data.add(jsonTable.getString("status"));
        dataList.add(data);
    }
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
    columnNames.add("purchaseid");
    columnNames.add("departmentcode");
    columnNames.add("deliveryattention");
    columnNames.add("completedstatus");
    columnNames.add("status");
    System.out.println(dataList);
    purchaseOrderTable = new JTable(dataList,columnNames);
```

This is how I am instantiating the table

```
private javax.swing.JTable purchaseOrderTable;
```

I do not get any errors, neither do I get any data on the table.
I thought maybe it was that the vector was empty and it is not. Any suggestions?

Comment: There does not seem any problem with the code. Have you checked **refresh** has length and **jsontable** and its data has values

Comment: yes Sir I have. Both **refresh** and **jsonTable** have all the values. It maybe some sort of visibility setting perhaps?